# What is my name? It's not "traveler"

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, computer-puzzle

[image: this is a red herring.]

The answer to this puzzle is my first name. What is it?

If no progress is made after a week or so, I'll slowly give hints. It's not too hard of a puzzle, so long as you take everything into account.

*Bonne chance !*

Comment: ROT13(Gur punenpgre fgevat jevggra ba terl boivbhfyl ybbxf nf n frq fpevcg.)

Comment: perhaos it can be read literally, executing does not look useful. `zngpu fgneg ercynpr vaperzrag` a referencr to current events - perhaps in the UK?

Comment: hidden text seems to be pointing towardsr kuaizip malware. I stopped there.

Comment: It is to do with regular expressions, that too - one after substituting a starting character of a specific word.

Answer (score 6):

Found few red herrings:

> In comment of image file is script for [Brainfuck](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fVzdaFwJstIHAzk4XDUTr2mlDgE0sEOpp69nZ2WnraQORHkhe7/9/AA) which translates to **HI!#$**
>  If you rewrite tiny text in **+** it will lead [Here](http://tio.run/##S8vP//9fKTk/L78oP6koMzVPV4lLKS2/okIvPbMkozRJLzgVKJZclFqi9P8/AA) and don't know what to do with result, since it is not valid url
>  There is text around visible text saying **Wrong pace**
>  Also there is tiny text **rot-11** and **Ii;Zz** - which I guess was "help", but I thought it was just saying "easy", because it looks like iZɪ."
>  So I guess I need to find a way to combine **rot-11** and **conorobrien-foxx.github.Seen-cret** or there is something more.
>  I have no idea what to do with **s/^/++>-/** when in image description there is **this is a red herring.** don't know where it belongs.

Comment: pbabeboevra-sbkk.tvguho.Frra-perg vf cebonoyl n TvgUho cntrf HEY. uggc://pbabeboevra-sbkk.tvguho.vb/frperg/

Comment: rot13(Gur pelcgvp f/^/++>-/ pbhyq gryy lbh gb nqq ++>- gb gur fgneg bs gur OenvaShpx Frdhrapr (eha vg nf "frq" jvgu gur oenvashpx-pbqr nf vachg). Gur arj Pbqr rinyhngrf gb ab1340. Znlor gung urycf. Ogj, va gur "r" bs gur jbeq "gur" va gur vzntr gurer vf n "y" juvpu gura tvirf "Jebat cynpr".)

Answer (score 5):

Your first name is

> Conor. Everything in the puzzle is a red herring besides the signature beneath it and the instruction to "take everything into account" (*everything* including the signature, and the allusion to your PSE account).

Comment: Creative :) but that isn't the solution.

Answer (score 4):

The image has a few hidden features:

> If we turn the contrast all the way up and brightness all the way up we get the following:
>  [image: bright image]
>  which shows the `rot-11` and `li;zZ` referenced by @JanIvan's [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/86179/42302) as well as the text 
>  `tio.run/##S8vP//9fKTk/L78oP6koMIVPV41LKS2/okIvPbMkoiRJLigVKJZcIFqi9P8/AA` 
>  Which leads us to a page the github referenced in @JanIvan's answer as well.
>  Note: I believe this transcription may be inaccurate

If on the other hand we

> Turn the contrast up and the brightness down, we get:
>  [image: dark]
>  Which seems to say "Wrong place", suggesting this image is a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

In risk of being overly simplistic, could it be:

> "my first name"
>   , and the puzzle was never about figuring out your name at all.

Comment: Not the answer, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting the title literally (with dad jokes), your full name is:

> not "traveller"

and so the first name is:

> not

Although I'm quite sure this is *not* the intended answer...

Comment: I'm all for dad jokes :) not the intended answer